# NEAT Error - AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'connections'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror, neat

I'm currently trying to create a NEAT algorithm to solve FlappyBird but am coming across an error while running my code (see title).  Currently I have set up my `run` function and my `eval_genomes` functions. I've simplified them to remove the `pygame` stuff and tried to keep it just to the `neat-python` relevant bits.

I know there are ways I could make this better, but I can someone help in finding how to solve the error I'm seeing below.

The error seems to stem from the `neat-python` module, but I've uninstalled and reinstalled it so there isn't anything wrong with the module.
I've run someone else's code and there's works so again module seems to work fine.

```
def run(config_path):
    config = neat.config.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction,
                         neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation,
                         config_path)

    p = neat.Population(config)

    p.add_reporter(neat.StdOutReporter(True))
    stats = neat.StatisticsReporter()
    p.add_reporter(stats)

    winner = p.run(eval_genomes,20)
```

```
def eval_genomes(genomes, config):
    run = True
    game = Game(WIN)

    nets = []
    ge = []
    birds = []

    for g in genomes:
        net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(g, config)
        nets.append(net)
        birds.append(Bird(WIN))
        g.fitness = 0
        ge.append(g)

    while run:
        if len(birds) = 0:
            run = False
            break

        for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
            bird.move()
            ge[x].fitness += 0.1

            output = nets[x].activate((bird.y,
                                      abs(bird.y - game.pipes[pipe_ind].height),
                                      abs(bird.y - game.pipes[pipe_ind].bottom)))

            if output[0] > 0.5:
                bird.jump()

        for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
            if game.check_collisions(bird):
                ge[x].fitness -= 1
                birds.pop(x)
                nets.pop(x)
                ge.pop(x)

        if game.pipe_passed(birds[0]):
            for g in ge:
                g.fitness += 5

        game.update()                        # Move all the other pieces
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ali/Documents/Coding Projects/Python/ToDo/Flappy-Bird-AI/Main.py", line 106, in <module>
    run(config_path)
  File "/Users/Ali/Documents/Coding Projects/Python/ToDo/Flappy-Bird-AI/Main.py", line 99, in run
    winner = p.run(eval_genomes,20)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neat/population.py", line 89, in run
    fitness_function(list(iteritems(self.population)), self.config)
  File "/Users/Ali/Documents/Coding Projects/Python/ToDo/Flappy-Bird-AI/Main.py", line 34, in eval_genomes
    net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(g, config)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neat/nn/feed_forward.py", line 33, in create
    connections = [cg.key for cg in itervalues(genome.connections) if cg.enabled]
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'connections'
```

Comment: error show problem with `connections` and there it shows also `genome.connections` sO I would try to check what is in `genome` - ie. `print(genome)` and `print(type(genome))`. It seems you use wrong value - `tuple` - but it should be some special object.

Comment: Got it sorted, thanks! 

By printing genome I saw it was giving me 
(1, genome object<>)

and so I changed my for loop to iterate as the following 

`for genome_id, genome in genomes:`

Answer (score 0):

This is very late, but I just had this problem and after a while I figured it out. I thought I would just post the solution here for anyone else who experiences this in the future. Your problem is when you are unpacking genomes.

```
for g in genomes:
    net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(g, config)
    nets.append(net)
    birds.append(Bird(WIN))
    g.fitness = 0
    ge.append(g)
```

To properly unpack genomes, it be must unpacked into 2 separate objects genome and genome_ID as so:

```
for genome_id, g in genomes:
    net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(g, config)
    nets.append(net)
    birds.append(Bird(WIN))
    g.fitness = 0
    ge.append(g)
```