# division by zero when population size is 1 neat-python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neat

Note: I submitted [an issue on their GitHub](https://github.com/CodeReclaimers/neat-python/issues/214), but looking at their GitHub, but it does not look like anyone will reply based on other issues submitted.

```
File "C:\Users\hunty\AppData\Local\RLBotGUIX\venv\lib\site-packages\neat\math_util.py", line 9, in mean
    return sum(map(float, values)) / len(values)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

When the population size of my model is set to 1, I receive a division by 0 error, when set to a number > 1, I don't get the error. I found a stack overflow page relating to this, but there was no solution.

Here is some of my code:
config file (the portion that matters):

```
[NEAT]
fitness_criterion     = max
fitness_threshold     = 9999
pop_size              = 2
reset_on_extinction   = False
```

eval/fitness function:

```
def main(gnomes, config):
    global net, ge
    net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork(gnomes[0], config)
    ge = gnomes[0]
    ge.fitness = 0
```

If you have a solution or need more code, please say so!

Whole Traceback:

```
 ****** Running generation 0 ******

Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hunty\AppData\Local\RLBotGUIX\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\hunty\AppData\Local\RLBotGUIX\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hunty\AppData\Local\RLBotGUIX\venv\lib\site-packages\rlbot\setup_manager.py", line 655, in run_agent
    bm.run()
  File "C:\Users\hunty\AppData\Local\RLBotGUIX\venv\lib\site-packages\rlbot\botmanager\bot_manager.py", line 196, in run
    self.load_agent()
  File "C:\Users\hunty\AppData\Local\RLBotGUIX\venv\lib\site-packages\rlbot\botmanager\bot_manager.py", line 117, in load_agent
    self.agent = agent_class(self.name, self.team, self.index)
  File "C:\Users\hunty\AppData\Local\RLBotGUIX\MyBots\learnie\src\bot.py", line 40, in __init__
    run(config_path)
  File "C:\Users\hunty\AppData\Local\RLBotGUIX\MyBots\learnie\src\bot.py", line 30, in run
    winner = p.run(main)
  File "C:\Users\hunty\AppData\Local\RLBotGUIX\venv\lib\site-packages\neat\population.py", line 89, in run
    fitness_function(list(iteritems(self.population)), self.config)
  File "C:\Users\hunty\AppData\Local\RLBotGUIX\MyBots\learnie\src\bot.py", line 18, in main
    net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork(gnomes[0], config)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'node_evals'
uninitialized_bot error reading header: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Comment: Please provide your full error trace info, and the line of your code that cause the error

Comment: I edited it to include the traceback

Comment: the line of code that caused the error is in the eval function

Comment: The cause of error trace you add is because you are not using `net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(gnomes[0], config)`, show the division by zero full error trace if you still have that problem

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm getting a new error, `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'connections'` inside the eval function on the `net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(gnomes[0], config)` line, tell me if you need the traceback

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65524441/neat-error-attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute-connections) first see if it can solve your problem

Comment: that was it, thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem, happy new year : )

Comment: ran into another issue down the line... The tutorial I'm following for the neat library is for an actual game made in python, the game I'm doing I have no control over, so I can't make the game itself tick, right now I just generate the genome in neat, and get the output every time the game ticks. I'm running into the issue that it is just rapidly going through generations, hundreds a second, how do I go about making it not move on until I tell it to?

Comment: As said by "Mr. For Example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65524441/neat-error-attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute-connections) fixed my error